# Using resource file not intended for localization?

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I want to dynamically change labels at run-time and I have a few options, but not sure which one is the best, and by best here, I mean I the leanest one without too much overhead:

1. A table that contains the label names along with their values.
2. Resource files to contain the values of the labels.
3. A class with
   just properties or constants that have the values of the
   labels.

For 2 and 3, I would keep them in a separate DLL so if I wanted to change just a label name, I would not have to deploy a whole application.

Comment: What kinds of overhead are you concerned about? Codebase? Network IO? File IO? Memory? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into satellite assembly in c#? This should make it easy to make localization in resource files: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm